# Компиляция SASS в webpack 2 - простейший случай

Tags: sass, webpack

Мне нужно, чтобы `Webpack` просто автоматически компилировал SASS в CSS при соханении `.sass` или `.scss` файлов. Подключать эти стили программно или делать из них сборки я пока не буду. Каковы будут **минимальные** настройки в `webpack.config.js` для решения данной задачи?

P. S. Использование `gulp` и других средств не желательно, ибо инструментов для быстрой и качественной веб-разработки должно быть достаточно, *но не более того*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать 'sass-loader' для решения вашей задачи.
Установка:

```
npm install sass-loader node-sass webpack --save-dev
```

Использование в webpack:

```
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
    ...
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [{
                loader: "style-loader"
            }, {
                loader: "css-loader"
            }, {
                loader: "sass-loader",
                options: {
                    includePaths: ["absolute/path/a", "absolute/path/b"]
                }
            }]
        }]
    }
};
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Пару вопросов по Вашему ответу: 1) Не понял из документации, что значит `includePaths`. Может быть первый элемент массива - директория исходников sass, а второй - директория для скомпилированных css? 2) Каким образом при данных настройках автоматически запускается компиляция при сохранении файлов?

Comment: 1) includePaths - пути по которым sass-loader будет пытаться найти, например картинки, если у вас в css будет указано в стилях url('images/logo.svg') и т.п.

Comment: 2) webpack --watch для запуска его в режиме "слежки"

Comment: Понял; и если можно, последний вопрос: а как webpack поймёт, откуда брать sass-исходники и куда класть выходные css? У меня, например, исходники в `app/scss`, а выходные в `public/css`.

Comment: У вас есть точка входа `module.exports = { entry: './main.js', ...` , в main.js вы импортируете какие-нибудь другие файлы скриптов и стилей, в которых вы, в свою очередь, тоже что-нибудь импортируете (например, `import '.main.css';`).  Вебпак пробегает по всему этому дереву и собирает его в '  output: {
    path: './source/built/',
    filename: 'app.js'
  },' дальше вам останется только подключить app.js и все скрипты и стили окажутся у вас в проекте.

Comment: Вот в том-то и дело, что я ничего не импортирую в js; у меня всё стили подключены напрямую в html. Как быть в этом случае?

Comment: На этот вопрос есть ответ на SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322958/can-i-use-webpack-to-generate-css-and-js-separately , его смысл в том, что вебпак ориентирован на сборку js зависимостей, но если очень хочется, то можно извернуться и собирать scss имопрты, но лучше так не делать.

Comment: Ещё раз благодарю Вас за ответ!

Comment: не за что, угощайтесь)

Answer (score 1):

Если вдруг понадобится компилить стили в отдельный файл, а не в сам документ, то можно подключить extract-text-webpack-plugin и сделать так:

```
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
    ...
    module: {
        rules: [{
             test: /\.scss$/,
             use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                 fallback: 'style-loader',
                 use: 'css-loader!sass-loader'
             })
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
       new ExtractTextPlugin('styles-[name].css')
    ]
};
```