# Согласование gulpfile.js и webpack.config.js для Webpack

Tags: javascript, gulp, webpack

После ответа на [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653118/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-sass-%D0%B2-webpack-2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9/) вопрос я решил, что пусть за всё, что связано с `JavaScript` (сборка модулей, Babel-конвертация, а также конкатенация и минификация JS-кода для продакшен-сборки) отвечает `Webpack`, а за всё остальное (например, компиляция `sass` и `jade`) пусть отвечает `gulp`.

Посмотрев [документацию](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-webpack) пакета `gulp-webpack`, я понял, что теперь все настройки webpack прописываются в `gulpfile.js`, а не в `webpack.config.js`, как при использовании "чистого" `webpack`. В этом вопросе я бы хотел рассмотреть случай, когда все настройки `webpack` останутся в `webpack.config.js`, а в `gulpfile` мы лишь пропишем запуск команды `webpack` для development-сборки JavaScript, и запуск продакшен-сборки JS.

На данный момент, пользуюсь примерно такой конфигурацией `webpack.config.js`:

```
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {

    context: __dirname + '/app',

    entry: "./main",

    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public/js',
        filename: 'index.js'
    },

    watch: NODE_ENV === 'development',

    watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 100
    },

    devtool:NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'cheap-inline-module-source-map' : null,

    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(NODE_ENV)
        })
    ],

    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
        extentions: ['', '.js']
    },

    resolveLoader: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
        moduleTemplates: ['*-loader', '*'],
        extentions: ['', '.js']
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015',
            optional: 'runtime'
        }]
    }
};

if (NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    module.exports.plugins.push(
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress:{
                warnings: false,
                drop_console: true,
                unsafe: true
            }
        })
    );
}
```

- Консольная комманда `webpack` запускает сборку модулей, при этом осуществляется конвертация в старый JS с помощью `Babel`. `NODE_ENV` по умолчанию имеет значение `development` и принимает это значение при запуске `webpack`.
- Продакшен-сборка выполняет также минификацию файла. Для запуска продакшен-сборки в Windows необходимо выполнить консольную команду `SET NODE_ENV=production` и затем - `webpack`.

Так как теперь за watching отвечает gulp, то соответствующие настройки из `webpack.config.js` можно убрать, а в gulpfile.js будет что-то вроде

```
gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'sass', 'jade', 'webpack'], function() {
    gulp.watch('development/jade/*.jade', ['jade']); 
    gulp.watch('development/sass/*.+(sass|scss)', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('development/es6/*.js', ['webpack']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

### Вопрос

Как будут выглядеть следующие два gulp-таска?

1. Таск, выполнение которого эквивалентно выполнению консольной команды `webpack` для development-сборки JS-файлов.
2. Таск, выполнение которого эквивалентно выполнению консольных комманд `SET NODE_ENV=production` → `webpack` для продакшен-сборки JS-файлов.

Wathcing файлов берёт на себя `gulp`. Все настройки `webpack` - в `webpack.config.js`; из `gulpfile.js` мы только запускаем нужные комманды вместо того, чтобы делать это из консоли.

### Заготовка кода для ответа

Я добавлю заготовку `gulpfile.js`, чтобы Вам было писать меньше кода:

```
var  gulp = require('gulp'), 
        webpack = require('gulp-webpack'),
        jade = require('gulp-jade'),
        sass = require('gulp-sass'),
        browserSync  = require('browser-sync'),
        autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('jade', function() { 
    // не по теме
});

gulp.task('sass', function(){ 
    // не по теме
});

gulp.task('webpack', function() {
  return gulp.src('development/es6/entry.js')
    .pipe(webpack()) // запуск development-сборки JS-файлов в соответствии с настройками в webpack.config.js
    .pipe(gulp.dest('development/'));
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() { 
    // не по теме
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'sass', 'webpack'], function() {
    gulp.watch('development/es6/*.js', ['webpack']); // watching берёт на себя gulp
    gulp.watch('development/jade/*.jade', ['jade']); 
    gulp.watch('development/sass/*.+(sass|scss)', ['sass']);
});


// development-сборка проекта; включает в себя вызов development-сборки webpack, что ранее делалось через консоль
gulp.task('default', ['watch']); 

// production-сборка проекта, включает в себя вызов production-сборки webpack, что ранее делалось через консоль
gulp.task('build', ['sass', 'webpack'], function() {

    // Нужен таск, эквивалентный вызову из консоли  SET NODE_ENV=production -> webpack

    // ... 

});
```

---

### Обновление

Таск `webpack` не запускается с помощью `exec = require('child_process').exec`. Никаких ошибок нет; судя по выводу в консоль, выполнение gulp-таска происходит в обычном режиме, как будто я не писал никаких иструкций, связанных с `webpack`.

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'), 
    // ...
    exec = require('child_process').exec,
    // ...
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

// ...

gulp.task('webpack', function(cb){ 
    exec('webpack');
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'jade', 'sass'], function() {
    gulp.watch('development/01_jade/**/*.jade', ['jade']); 
    gulp.watch('development/02_sass/*.+(sass|scss)', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('development/03_es6/*.js', ['webpack']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

**webpack.config.js** (Используется `webpack2`)

```
'use strict';
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

module.exports = {

    context: __dirname + '/development',

    entry: './03_es6/main.js',

    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/development/js/',
        filename: 'index.js'
    },

    module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.jsx?$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: ['babel-loader']
                }
            ]
        }

    //watch: NODE_ENV === 'development'
};
```

Comment: отписал в комменте под своим постом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0) Nota Bene! Работу Вебпака можна модифицировать 2 способами 1-консольно (cli) и 2-в конфигах Вебпака

1) нужно решить где изменять настройки сборки, тоесть

а) хранить в .env в свойстве NODE_ENV и читать process.env.NODE_ENV

б) забить на это и делать модификацыю конфига Вебпака на лету

в) с Галпа запускать консольные команды спомощью `exec = require('child_process').exec;`

Лично я пользуюсь методом б)

```

```
var gulpWebpack = require('gulp-webpack'); 

...some code

gulp.task('webpack', function (done) {
    let webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');

    //модифицируем конфиг как нам нужно, и если нужно
    webpackConfig.devtool = 'cheap-inline-module-source-map'; //исходя из 'development' ? 'cheap-inline-module-source-map' : null,
    webpackConfig.progress = true; // выводит прогресс

    //подключаем нжуные плагины
    //не забываем о тех что уже подклбчены в конфиге
    webpackConfig.plugins.push(
        new webpack.ProgressPlugin(function (percentage, msg) {
            // выводим в консоль Галпа Прогресс Вебпака в виде какой нам нравится
            // для удобства был использован сторонний модуль
            var log = require('color-log');
            log.single.info('----', Math.round(percentage * 100) + '%', msg)
        })
    );

    //если нужно удалить плагин, например CommonsChunk Plugin
    webpackConfig.plugins.map(function (plugin, index) {
       if (!!plugin.ident && !!plugin.ident.match('CommonsChunkPlugin')) {
            webpackConfig.plugins.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });

     gulp.src(['development/es6/entry.js', 'массив энтри поинтов', '...'])
          .pipe(gulpWebpack(webpackConfig))
          .on('error', () => {
             //код при ошибке
          })
          .pipe(gulp.dest('development/'))
          .on('end', () => {
                //код при окончании
                //например сказать об окончании Gulp Таска
                done();
          });
});
```

```

во 2 случае вам нужно будет поменять `webpackConfig.devtool = null,` так что можно просто создать 2 Таска Гапла где будет меняться этот параметр и вызывать 1 и ту же функцию сборки. В дальнейшем можно еще более разнообразить сборки

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! К сожалению, не получилось запустить `exec = require('child_process').exec;`. Если Вас не затруднит, посмотрите, пожалуйста, раздел "Обновление" в поле вопроса.

Comment: 1) вы точно запустити Галп который зпустит Вебпак из той самой области где есть доступ к Вебпаку, иначе он просто не увидет его
2) если Галп запускает Вебпак через `exec` то вы ничего не увидите, Вебпак будет как бы в фоне работать
3) так что лучше все таки через gulp-webpack (метод б) - так надежней, вы котнролируете процесс, вы выводите логи